# Changing color CSS/SASS in VS code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, color-picker

Have you found some extensions that are not time consuming like a color picker when typing code in CSS and such?
Thank you!

Comment: It's built right into VS Code no? If you type in a CSS color (Hex or rgb()), it will show you the picker when you hover over the color value - a bit tricky definitely when you are used to chrome having a clickable box.

Comment: To expand upon @MrRobboto's answer, you can click the hex/rgb/hsl value to toggle between syntaxes.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen do you mean in Chrome dev tools? I just tried that in VS Code and no joy...

Comment: @chriskirknielsen nevermind, figured it out - damn, why do they make all these features so tricky? In chrome it's so easy

Comment: @MrRobboto No, talking about VS Code alright!

Comment: Lol got it - yeah, so funky how they did that

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted this - yeah it's there in VS Code but it is obviously a tricky feature to use - no problem with this post to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can hover over CCS colors in VS Code and it will show you a color picker - seems like what you're going for.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? maybe i wasn't clear enough, is there a color picker so that you can tag colors outside VS code. That would immensely improve my workflow.

Comment: Yeah I totally don't know what you mean by tagging colors outside VS Code. Your question just asks for a color picker in VS Code so I think my answer works for that - you should edit your question if you're looking for something else.